# tmux not re-attaching

Tags: macos, zsh, putty, tmux, iterm

I recently switched from using screen to tmux (obtained through macports), as I like the feature set more. However, I can't seem to get tmux to reattach from an alternate location, like I can screen.

At home on my mac, I will open up iTerm2, my default shell is zsh, and I will begin a tmux session with `tmux`. I get all my spits set up, ssh'd into the proper servers, etc., and work for a while. Time to go to work. `<C-a> d` - tmux detaches.

I get to work, where I use a windows xp machine. I fire up putty, ssh into my mac back at home, attempt a `tmux attach`, and get an error message:

**`no sessions`**

I cannot seem to determine why this would happen. I am not afraid to dig into this, but don't even know where to start. Thoughts?

P.S. I have already removed my .tmux.conf file, so it's using the default config.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*tmux* stores its server socket in a directory under the directory specified by the TMPDIR environment variable.

In your GUI session you probably end up with a TMPDIR that points to somewhere under `/var` (e.g. `/var/folders/mV/mVip4IQ4EXOriTiLJmeSuk+++Tc/-Tmp-/`).

When you are logged in through SSH, you probably end up without a TMPDIR set, so *tmux* looks under `/tmp/` for its socket.

On a 10.6 system, here is my TMPDIR with *zsh*/﻿*Terminal*, and with *zsh*/SSH:

```
% echo local: ${TMPDIR-unset}; ssh localhost 'echo remote: ${TMPDIR-unset}'
local: /var/folders/mV/mVip4IQ4EXOriTiLJmeSuk+++Tc/-Tmp-/
remote: unset
```

If you know the value you need to use for TMPDIR, you can specify it when attaching (or running some other *tmux* command outside of the session itself):

```
TMPDIR=/var/folders/mV/mVip4IQ4EXOriTiLJmeSuk+++Tc/-Tmp-/ tmux attach
```

If you do not know the directory your GUI session was using you might be able to find it with something like this (the syntax is specific to *zsh*; it searches under `/var/folders/` for a directory named `-Tmp-` that is owned by the current user):

```
echo /var/folders/**/*/-Tmp-(U/)
```

To avoid problems in the future, you might want to unset TMPDIR before starting your server (or set it to something that you can more easily predict).

Comment: Running an `unset TMPDIR` prior to starting my tmux session did solve the problem. Huge props.

Comment: If you are trying to find the tmpdir in bash, try

    `find /var/folders -type d -name "-Tmp-" -user $(whoami) 2>/dev/null`

This looks in /var/folders for a directory (d) with name "-Tmp-" owned by you. Since /var/folders will contain a lot of directories that will be permission denied, the stderr is also redirected to the bit bucket.

Edit: premature enter

Comment: `TMPDIR=/var/folders/mV/mVip4IQ4EXOriTiLJmeSuk+++Tc/-Tmp-/ tmux attach` didn't work for me but `TMUX_TMPDIR=/var/folders/mV/mVip4IQ4EXOriTiLJmeSuk+++Tc/-Tmp-/ tmux attach` with a valid value for my TMPDIR found with the lsof command below.

Comment: As an alternative, you can manually specify the location of the socket with `tmux -S /Users/yourname/.tmux-socket attach` or similar. (You need to use the same `-S` value when you create the session and each time you reattach to it.) Choosing a location in your home directory means the socket will not be purged out from under you.

Comment: make sure you're not explicitly calling other shell programs in your init conf, such as `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash`

calling bash might mess if you're also using bash.

Answer (score 45):

In my case, apparently temp folder was cleaned.
[This blog post](https://inuits.eu/blog/tmux-still-alive-saying-no-sessions) helped me recover my “lost” session:

> I finally got the solution: sending the signal 10 forced tmux to recreate sockets. After that I could run tmux again without losing my session:
>
> ```
> $ killall -10 tmux
> ```

Comment: I had this same issue today, and came across the same blog! It works, but I was confused about *why* it works. It turns out that signal 10 is a *user-defined signal*, and [tmux says it will "recreate the server socket on SIGUSR1"](https://github.com/ThomasAdam/tmux/blob/814e40522cb611895e84fc2aaf58d5d0ca9ba348/CHANGES#L552).

Comment: This worked for me, but *not* when I had a second tmux session open: I think the sockets clashed meaning that the original session could not recreate them.

Comment: The **parent directory** is not recreated before the sockets, you have to do it before sending the kill signal.

Comment: The blog is not available any more. The kill -10 <tmux pid> works well indeed. Just curious the reason, and how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 7):

The `-U` option of `lsof` lists open socket files, so `lsof -U | grep '^tmux'` will list all of the sockets in use by *tmux*. If you're not logged in as the same user that started *tmux*, you will need to use `sudo`.

The last column of each row is the name of the file. The files you care about start with a `/`.

The rows you're looking for will look something like this:

```
tmux 1234  username 6u unix 0xffffffabcd123456 0t0 /private/var/folders/M8/M8tFwolmH08fOvJ+-35VI++++TM/-Tmp-/tmux-502/default
tmux 56789 username 6u unix 0xffffff123456789a 0t0 /private/tmp/tmux-502/default
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a variation on the `lsof` suggestion that I have been using with some success to “recover” the TMPDIR variable which can help working around a bunch of annoyances. The advantage, I suppose, is that one can be a little more exacting about what `lsof` returns and easier to parse out the correct value (on the off-chance at some point some atypical chars, but still valid, ever output).

A quick, one-liner is:

```
$ lsof -Fn -d6 -aUc tmux | grep ^n | cut -c2-
/private/var/folders/_l/f_n8blps05xfnkw6fs3dcn_80000gp/T/tmux-502/default
```

I use the following script (could also be a function in ~/.bash_profile or other appropriate place I suppose):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "${TMPDIR}" ]]; then
  while read line; do
      case $line in
      n*) line="${line#n}"
          export TMPDIR="${line%%/tmux-$(id -u)/*}"
          ;;
      esac;
  done < <(lsof -Fn -d6 -aUc tmux)
else
    echo ">> \$TMPDIR already defined: $TMPDIR" 1>&2
fi
```

https://gist.github.com/jps3/769d50a6a7611949473b